# Two-step induction of inductive predicate on Streams

Tags: coq, coinductive-type, induction

If I want to have an induction principle for `nat`s from `n` to `n+2`, I can define and prove this lemma (from "[Can I tell Coq to do induction from n to n+2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998991/can-i-tell-coq-to-do-induction-from-n-to-n2)" on StackOverflow):

```
Lemma nat_ind2 (P : nat -> Prop) :
  P 0 -> P 1 ->
  (forall n, P n -> P (S n) -> P (S (S n))) ->
  forall n, P n.
Proof.
  intros H0 H1 Hstep n.
  enough (P n /\ P (S n)) by easy.
  induction n; intuition.
Qed.
```

If I want to define in a similar way an induction principle for `Exists` from `Coq.Lists.Streams`, how should I do it?
Looking at the definition of `Exists_ind`, I came up with the following principle. Is this the one I am looking for? Are all hypothesis necessary? Why is the base hypothesis different from the ones used in `nat`? is it because the type we are predicating on (`Stream`) is coinductive?

```
Lemma Exists_ind2 :
  forall (A : Type) (P P0 : Stream A -> Prop),
    (forall x : Stream A, P x -> P0 x) ->
    (forall x : Stream A, P x -> P0 (tl x)) -> (* is this hypothesis necessary? *)
    (forall x : Stream A, Exists P (tl (tl x)) -> P0 (tl (tl x)) -> P0 (tl x) -> P0 x) ->
    forall x : Stream A, Exists P x -> P0 x.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the induction principle generated by the following definition ?

```
Inductive Exists2 (P: Stream A -> Prop) : Stream A -> Prop:=
  here: forall s, P s -> Exists2 P s
| next : forall x s, P s -> Exists2 P (Cons x s)
| next2 : forall x y s, Exists2 P s -> Exists2 P (Cons x (Cons y s)). 


About Exists2_ind.
```

Or something similar ?

Comment: Yes, `Exists2_ind` is indeed what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a similar solution, here's how I solved the problem.

#### First solution

Define a inductive predicate `Exists2` as suggested by [@Pierre Castéran](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/1078/pierre-cast%c3%a9ran), and then prove that `forall P s, Exists P s <-> Exists2 P s`.

```
Inductive Exists2 (P: Stream A -> Prop) : Stream A -> Prop:=
  | Here2    : forall s, P s -> Exists2 P s
  | There2   : forall x s, P s -> Exists2 P (Cons x s)
  | Further2 : forall x y s, Exists2 P s -> Exists2 P (Cons x (Cons y s)). 

Lemma Exists_iff_Exists2 : forall (P : Stream A -> Prop) (s : Stream A), Exists P s <-> Exists2 P s.
Proof.
  intros P s. split; intro H.
  - enough (Exists2 P s /\ forall x, Exists2 P (Cons x s)) by easy.
    induction H as [s H | s H IHExists].
    + split.
      * apply Here2. apply H.
      * intro x. apply There2. apply H.
    + destruct s as [y s]. split.
      * apply IHExists.
      * intro x. apply Further2. apply IHExists.
  - induction H as [s H | x s H | x y s H IHExists2].
    + apply Here. apply H.
    + apply Further. apply Here. apply H.
    + apply Further. apply Further. apply IHExists2.
Qed.
```

When an two-step induction on some `H : Exists P s`, it's sufficient to `apply Exists_iff_Exists2 in H. induction H.`

#### Second solution

Prove the following lemma:

```
Lemma Exists_ind2:
  forall (A : Type) (P P0 : Stream A -> Prop),
    (forall s : Stream A, P s -> P0 s) ->
    (forall (x : A) (s : Stream A), P s -> P0 (Cons x s)) ->
    (forall (x y : A) (s : Stream A), Exists P s -> P0 s -> P0 (Cons x (Cons y s))) ->
    forall s : Stream A, Exists P s -> P0 s.
Proof.
  intros A P P0 Hbase Hbase' Hstep s H.
  enough (P0 s /\ forall a, P0 (Cons a s)) by easy.
  induction H as [s H | s H IHExists].
  + split.
    * apply Hbase. apply H.
    * intro x. apply Hbase'. apply H.
  + destruct s as [y s]. replace (tl (Cons y s)) with s by reflexivity. split.
    * apply IHExists.
    * intro x. apply Hstep.
      -- apply H.
      -- apply IHExists.
Qed.
```

This lemma is indeed identical to the `Exists2_ind` that is generated by the inductive definition of `Exists2` of the previous solution, with the only difference that all occurrences of `Exists2` are replaced with `Exists`.

The proof itself is identical to the one of the lemma of the first solution, with the difference that instead of applying `Exists2`'s constructors we apply inductive hypothesis.

---

Maybe this problem is trivial for many, don't bash me.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, both your solutions remind me of a similar discussion about the transitive closure of a binary relation. We wanted to be able to perform induction proofs on `x R^* y` in three modes: from left to right, from right to left, and from the "middle".  This led to define three inductive predicates and prove their logical equivalence.

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.html

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Relations.Operators_Properties.html